# How to display cursor (Reticle) in VR - mode using React-vr?

Tags: android, react-360

https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/input.html
Based on this documentation I have done sample. In browser I can see the mouse pointer which is default. In Android chrome I don't see any cursor or pointer. But touch works and colour of the text is getting updated on touch. When I am switching into VR mode there is no cursor visible.

Attached screen shot for reference.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect Gear VR inputs in React VR scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259273/how-do-i-detect-gear-vr-inputs-in-react-vr-scene)

Answer (score 3):

meybe this page help u
https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/86

So I will try to use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-raycaster

Comment: Nice, I have used this one, this works, but I made "cursorVisibility" as "visible", not "auto" as in current docs

Answer (score 1):

For the new React360 framework you can also use the SimpleRayCaster:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-raycaster

In your client.js file add the following to the imports:

```
import SimpleRaycaster from "./SimpleRaycaster";
```

Then add the following lines after the r360 instance is created:

```
  r360.controls.addRaycaster(SimpleRaycaster);
  r360.compositor.setCursorVisibility('visible');
```